# Problema con hacer consulta doble en php

Tags: php

Este es el código que estoy intentando y la segunda consulta no me la hace, en el segundo while me sale un mensaje. Intento guardar en un vector las personas con un array y sus roles, si no se pueden hacer consultas dobles, de que manera se puede hacer? [image: mensaje]

```
    if ($stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios where Email != ?')) {
        $u = null;
        $usus = [];
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($email, $nombre, $pass, $foto);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            $sql = "SELECT roles.Nombre_rol FROM roles, roles_asignados, usuarios WHERE usuarios.Email=roles_asignados.Id_usuario and roles_asignados.Id_rol=roles.Id_rol and usuarios.Email ='" . $email . "'";
            $result = $this->conexion->query($sql);
            //print_r($result);
            $u = new Persona($email, $nombre, $pass, $foto, '');
            $rol = null;


              while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

              $rol[] = $row[0];
              //print_r($rol);
              }

              $u->setRol($rol);
              $usus[] = $u;

        }
        return $usus;
    }
```

[image: Este es el error que me da cuando hago un print_r de lo que devuelve, me lleva a esa línea que muestro]

Comment: El mensaje es un *warning*, no un error. Algún analizador de código instalado advierte de que no es bueno anidar muchas estructuras de control: if -> while -> while. No está relacionado con ningún problema particular, simplemente te aconseja dividir el código en funciones más pequeñas

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta y he agregado el error que da al hacer un print_r de lo que devuelve la consulta, como ves me lleva a esa línea del warning

Answer (score 1):

yo tambien tuve un problema parecido al tuyo en una vista hacia bastantes consultas, al final llegue a la conclusion que el problema resulta en los hilos que maneja el pc, que saturan la vista por eso el pone los errores o advertencias. Creeria yo que debes replantear la forma como haces esas consultas y simplificar las peticiones a mysql, de esta forma no saturaras los hilos del pc. A mi me toco replantear el codigo y de esta forma logre no saturar los hilos del pc.

Comment: Si, al final lo he tenido que hacer de otra manera porque así no funciona